# Выдает ошибку script.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: btn2.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var ul = document.getElementById('btn2');
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var story = list.getElementsByClassName('item');
var popup = document.getElementsByClassName('popup')[0];
var close = document.querySelector('.close');

function addItem() {
 var newList = document.createElement("li");
 newList.innerHTML = "Почитать 30мин";
 newList.className = "item";
 list.appendChild(newList);
}

function delItem() {
 list.removeChild(story[0]);
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', addItem);
btn2.addEventListener('click', delItem);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="main" id="main">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="main_field">
   <ul id="list">
    <li class="item">Первая задача</li>

   </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <button class="main_btn center-block" id="btn1">
     Добавить элемент
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <button class="main_btn center-block" id="btn2">
     Удалить лишний
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 

 <div class="popup">
  <div class="close">&times</div>
  <p>Все дела на сегодня выполнены!</p>
 </div>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var btn2 = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
```

или

```
var btn2 = document.querySelector('ul');
```